# Pandas - Generate Columns Based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is sample dataset:

```
>>> df
   vn    pt    st nst stb mid
0   a   0.1     a   b   0   3
1   a   0.2     a   b   4   3
2   a   0.3     a   b   1   3
3   a   0.3     b   a   1   3
4   a   0.4     a   b   1   3
5   a   0.4     a   b   2   3
6   a   0.5     c   b   6   3
7   a   0.5     c   b   0   3
8   a   0.6     c   b   1   3
9   a   1.1     b   c   2   3
10  a   1.2     b   c   1   3
11  a   1.3     d   b   6   3
12  a   1.4     d   b   0   3
13  a   1.4     d   b   1   3
14  a   1.5     e   d   2   3
15  a   1.6     d   e   0   3
16  a   0.1     d   y   1   7
17  a   0.2     y   d   4   7
18  a   0.3     y   d   1   7
19  a   0.4     y   x   3   7
20  a   0.5     x   z   0   7
21  a   0.6     p   z   2   7
22  a   0.6     z   p   6   7
23  a   1.1     p   q   3   7
```

From this dataset, I want to create two new columns `sr` and `nsr`. Few things to remember: `stb` value represents corresponding value of `st`. When there is a new string is enrolled in `st` or `nst` by default `sr=0`, `nsr=0` accordingly.

Codition for `st`:1.When value of `st` is consecutively same `sr=sr+stb`,2.When value of `nst` moves to `st` `sr=nsr+stb`,3.When there is a new value assigned to `st`, `st=stb`

Codition for `nst`:1.When value of `nst` is consecutively same `nsr` will remain same(no change),2.When value of `st` moves to `nst` value of previous `sr` should be returned to next `nsr`,3.When there is a new value assigned to `nst`, `nsr=0`

The iteration continues until `mid` is consecutive same value(When a different mid appears, it will start iteration from the beginning). To generate these two columns have a look at the following example:

```
st nst stb  sr                                             nsr
 a   b   0  0+0=0(sr=sr+stb)                               0(nst newly enrolled, set to 0)
 a   b   4  0+4=4(sr=sr+stb)                               0(remains same)
 a   b   1  4+1=5(sr=sr+stb)                               0(remains same)
 b   a   1  0+1=1(sr=nsr+stb),bcz b moves from nst to st   5(shifts from sr to nsr)
 a   b   1  5+1=6(sr=nsr+stb),bcz a moves from nst to st   1(shifts from sr to nsr)
 a   b   2  6+2=8(sr=sr+stb)                               1(remains same)
 c   b   6  0+6=6(sr=sr+stb),c newly inserted              1(remains same)
...........
(will continue recursively until `mid` is unique)
...........
```

**Expected output:**

```
   vn    pt    st  sr nsr
0   a   0.1     a   0   0
1   a   0.2     a   4   0
2   a   0.3     a   5   0
3   a   0.3     b   1   5
4   a   0.4     a   6   1
5   a   0.4     a   8   1
6   a   0.5     c   6   1
7   a   0.5     c   6   1
8   a   0.6     c   7   1
9   a   1.1     b   3   7
10  a   1.2     b   4   7
11  a   1.3     d   6   4
12  a   1.4     d   6   4
13  a   1.4     d   7   4
14  a   1.5     e   2   7
15  a   1.6     d   7   2
16  a   0.1     d   1   0
17  a   0.2     y   4   1
18  a   0.3     y   5   1
19  a   0.4     y   8   0
20  a   0.5     x   0   0
21  a   0.6     p   2   0
22  a   0.6     z   6   2
23  a   1.1     p   5   0
```

Comment: Is this problem clear for everyone? :/

Comment: Should `sr` on row `16` be 8 instead of 1 ?   Also, please elaborate how `nsr` is calculated.

Comment: `sr` should be 1 on row `16`. Because the loop continues until `mid` is unique. On row `15` `mid=3` whether on row `16` `mid=7`. So, loop will start again from the beginning. However, there is no calculation in `nsr`. It will just return the value of the previous `sr` when `nst` shifts to `st`. Hope you got it.

Comment: `nsr` row 11 why it is 4 ?  Since there is no shift from `nst` to `st` although the value of `st` changed.

Comment: On row 11, new value of `st` has appeared. Therefore value of `sr` by default 0. But `stb=6`. So, `sr=sr+stb=0+6=6`. For `nsr`, b shifts from `st` to `nst`. So from row 10, `sr=4` will be returned to `nsr` on row 11 and `nsr` becomes 4.

Comment: So there is not only when `nst` shifts to `st` but also `st` shifts to `nst` that needs to update `nsr`.   Please make it clear of this in the question.  Also, please state it clear the role of `mid` in the question. `(will continue recursively until 'mid' is unique)` is not clear enough of its role

Comment: Will update it soon. Thanks.

Comment: `nsr` rows 20 why not 8 and row 23 why not 6 ?  Both have `st`  changed and `nst` shift to `st`, so should take the previous row values of `sr` of 8 and 6 ?

Comment: when there a new value assigned to `st` or `nst`, `sr` and `nsr` would be by default 0 accordingly. For eg `st=p` afterthat `st=q`, then `sr`=`sr+stbat`=`0+stbat`=`stbat`

Comment: I have edited my problem. Is there anything still not clear? @SeaBean

Comment: There is still some inconsistency to me.  E.g. Whenever there is a new value assigned to nst, nsr=0.  Then, `nsr` row 3 should be 0 instead of 5 ?   I can provide you my partial works below for your reference.  The `sr` column already got your expected results. `nsr` column need more works.  You can take it as a reference.

Comment: "Whenever there is a new value assigned to nst, nsr=0" This new means a new value that never appeared in `st`or `nst` both before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the partial solution so far, based on question and discussions in comments:

`sr` column already got the expected results but `nsr` need some further works:

```
df['sr'] = df.groupby(['mid', 'st'])['stb'].cumsum()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   vn   pt st nst  stb  mid  sr
0   a  0.1  a   b    0    3   0
1   a  0.2  a   b    4    3   4
2   a  0.3  a   b    1    3   5
3   a  0.3  b   a    1    3   1
4   a  0.4  a   b    1    3   6
5   a  0.4  a   b    2    3   8
6   a  0.5  c   b    6    3   6
7   a  0.5  c   b    0    3   6
8   a  0.6  c   b    1    3   7
9   a  1.1  b   c    2    3   3
10  a  1.2  b   c    1    3   4
11  a  1.3  d   b    6    3   6
12  a  1.4  d   b    0    3   6
13  a  1.4  d   b    1    3   7
14  a  1.5  e   d    2    3   2
15  a  1.6  d   e    0    3   7
16  a  0.1  d   y    1    7   1
17  a  0.2  y   d    4    7   4
18  a  0.3  y   d    1    7   5
19  a  0.4  y   x    3    7   8
20  a  0.5  x   z    0    7   0
21  a  0.6  p   z    2    7   2
22  a  0.6  z   p    6    7   6
23  a  1.1  p   q    3    7   5
```

Partial work for `nsr`:

```
m1 = df['st'].ne(df['st'].groupby(df['mid']).shift())
m2 = df['st'].eq(df['nst'].shift())
m3 = df['nst'].eq(df['st'].shift())
m = m1 & (m2 | m3)

df['nsr'] = np.where(m, df['sr'].shift(), np.nan)

m11 = df['mid'] != df['mid'].shift()
df['nsr'] = np.where(m11, 0, df['nsr'])

df['nsr'] = df['nsr'].ffill(downcast='infer')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   vn   pt st nst  stb  mid  sr  nsr
0   a  0.1  a   b    0    3   0    0
1   a  0.2  a   b    4    3   4    0
2   a  0.3  a   b    1    3   5    0
3   a  0.3  b   a    1    3   1    5
4   a  0.4  a   b    1    3   6    1
5   a  0.4  a   b    2    3   8    1
6   a  0.5  c   b    6    3   6    1
7   a  0.5  c   b    0    3   6    1
8   a  0.6  c   b    1    3   7    1
9   a  1.1  b   c    2    3   3    7
10  a  1.2  b   c    1    3   4    7
11  a  1.3  d   b    6    3   6    4
12  a  1.4  d   b    0    3   6    4
13  a  1.4  d   b    1    3   7    4
14  a  1.5  e   d    2    3   2    7
15  a  1.6  d   e    0    3   7    2
16  a  0.1  d   y    1    7   1    0
17  a  0.2  y   d    4    7   4    1
18  a  0.3  y   d    1    7   5    1
19  a  0.4  y   x    3    7   8    1
20  a  0.5  x   z    0    7   0    8
21  a  0.6  p   z    2    7   2    8
22  a  0.6  z   p    6    7   6    2
23  a  1.1  p   q    3    7   5    6
```

### Edit

Here is another trial attempt to complete the partial works left behind last time.

With addition of a new set of processing, the desired values of `nsr` is finally achieved.

```
m1 = df['st'].ne(df['st'].groupby(df['mid']).shift())
m2 = df['st'].eq(df['nst'].shift())
m3 = df['nst'].eq(df['st'].shift())
m = m1 & (m2 | m3)

df['nsr'] = np.where(m, df['sr'].shift(), np.nan)

## Handle the condition with a new value of `nst` is seen AND
## at the same time, it is NOT shifted from `st`:
# start of new codes
m21 = df['nst'] != df['nst'].shift()
m22 = df['nst'] != df['st'].shift()
df['nsr'] = np.where(m21 & m22, 0, df['nsr'])
# end of new codes

m11 = df['mid'] != df['mid'].shift()
df['nsr'] = np.where(m11, 0, df['nsr'])

df['nsr'] = df['nsr'].ffill(downcast='infer')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   vn   pt st nst  stb  mid  sr  nsr
0   a  0.1  a   b    0    3   0    0
1   a  0.2  a   b    4    3   4    0
2   a  0.3  a   b    1    3   5    0
3   a  0.3  b   a    1    3   1    5
4   a  0.4  a   b    1    3   6    1
5   a  0.4  a   b    2    3   8    1
6   a  0.5  c   b    6    3   6    1
7   a  0.5  c   b    0    3   6    1
8   a  0.6  c   b    1    3   7    1
9   a  1.1  b   c    2    3   3    7
10  a  1.2  b   c    1    3   4    7
11  a  1.3  d   b    6    3   6    4
12  a  1.4  d   b    0    3   6    4
13  a  1.4  d   b    1    3   7    4
14  a  1.5  e   d    2    3   2    7
15  a  1.6  d   e    0    3   7    2
16  a  0.1  d   y    1    7   1    0
17  a  0.2  y   d    4    7   4    1
18  a  0.3  y   d    1    7   5    1
19  a  0.4  y   x    3    7   8    0
20  a  0.5  x   z    0    7   0    0
21  a  0.6  p   z    2    7   2    0
22  a  0.6  z   p    6    7   6    2
23  a  1.1  p   q    3    7   5    0
```

Comment: Whenever there is a new value assigned to `nst`, `nsr=0` same logic applicable for `st`. This new means a new value that never appeared in `st`or `nst` both before. Can you give another try `nsr` column?

Comment: @pythonnoob  Partial work for `nst` for your reference.  You can try modify it based on your understanding on the question.  I got something to do and can't continue the works right now.  Good luck!  Hope you arrive at your solution very soon!

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could complete the solution for `nsr`. I find it too complex. @SeaBean

Comment: @pythonnoob  See the edit above.  Resumed from last partial works of second part and added new set of codes to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

(Partial attempt waiting for feedback − doesn’t fit into a comment.)

From your explanations, `sr` is different cumulative sum of `stb` for each `st`, `nst` pair. However this doesn’t quite fit with your expected outputs:

```
>>> df['sr'] = df.groupby(['nst', 'st'])['stb'].cumsum()
>>> df[['sr']].join([expected['sr'].rename('expected'), (df['sr'] - expected['sr']).rename('diff')])
    sr  expected  diff
0    0         0     0
1    4         4     0
2    5         5     0
3    1         1     0
4    6         6     0
5    8         8     0
6    6         6     0
7    6         6     0
8    7         7     0
9    2         3    -1
10   3         4    -1
11   6         6     0
12   6         6     0
13   7         7     0
14   2         2     0
15   0         7    -7
16   1         1     0
17   4         4     0
18   5         5     0
19   3         8    -5
20   0         0     0
21   2         2     0
22   6         6     0
23   3         5    -2
```

What happens on rows 9, 10, 15, 19, and 23?

For example row 9 is the first with `b, c`, if I compare it to row 3 the first with `b, a` it should be `0+3` the same way row 3 is `0+1`.

Comment: I have edited my problem. Can you look once again please?